# woocommerce product custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In the [article](http://gerhardpotgieter.com/2013/09/17/woocommerce-custom-product-fields/) they have explained how to add custom product fields, BUT I didn't understand in that code for which specific product...

I mean for which product page, they're adding custom field?

To be more clear, where to add my product id in that code so that my custom fields would appear in my required product page?

Sorry, if it's a dumb question (I am not good at PHP).

Comment: What are you asking? The code provided by Gerhard adds the custom fields to every product's admin and then displays the value on any single product page that has the custom field filled out.

Comment: @helgatheviking I dont want to appear custom fields in every product page..My custom fields are differnt for each product page..

Comment: Well nothing appears on the product page if you leave the field blank. I still don't understand your question, maybe try to re-phrase it, add a screenshot, etc.

Answer (score 0):

They are just showing you a way to add custom field in your edit product/ add new product page under general tab. The output will show on Single product page and Optionally they have shown you the code to show it on product archive pages, if you want to. Archive pages include shop, product category, product tag etc.